# How to play Percussion using MIDI.js

Tags: javascript, midi

I am trying to play Percussion using MIDI.js

Looking at the General MIDI specification at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI#Piano Percussion is listed separated from the 128 instruments MIDI supports.

Nevertheless, when I load the instruments using MIDI.loadPlugin method, I have to pass an array with the name of the instruments.

**Question**: What instrument name I pass to loadPlugin() to indicate I want to play Percussion?
Should I replace the soundfont of one of those 128 instruments with the soundfont of the percussion and load that instrument instead? Or is there a better way to play percussion?

For a better idea of the player I am working on take a look at http://www.ripbeat.com/PianoLesson/15199/Vida-Loca-Francisco-Cespedes

Comment: What "sound font" are you using? Does it have percussion sounds?

Comment: I am using the sound fonts from https://github.com/gleitz/midi-js-soundfonts it has the sounds for the 128 instruments including the percussive. But percussion needs of a separate sound font as far as I understand, correct?

Comment: Where exactly does it have percussion sounds?

Comment: The midi-js-soundfonts library contains sounds for Tinkle Bell, Steel Drums, Taiko Drum, Synth Drum, etc that are all Percussive instruments. For example we are playing instrument 118 (Synth Drum) every time the sound comes on channel 10 (percussion) but that is not right. There should be a sound-font for percussion different from Synth Drum.

Comment: That sound fonts does not have any percussion instruments for channel 10. (I don't know why; this makes it useless for many kinds of music.)

Comment: Is there a solution for this by now? The soundfonts available with MIDI.js still do not support all the mentioned in "General MIDI Level 1 Percussion" at https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/gm-level-1-sound-set